# Full hint on table inside a view

Tags: oracle, query-performance, sql-view

I'm using Orace 11g.

let's say I have a view that contains a table, and a query on that view.

How can I add a full hint on the inner table when I query the view?

Is there a way to add that hint on the view?

Example:

```
-- View V contains table T
create or replace view V as
select *
from   T
where  col1 > 1000
and    col2 <> 'David';

-- My query
select *
from   V
where  col3 < 999;
```

Comment: My understanding for a non materialized view is that its performance will just mirror whatever the underlying table is doing.  So, you can try adding a hint on the underlying table.

Comment: A lot of queries use this view.. I would like to change only that query because I dont want to hurt other queries.

Comment: Can you create a materialized view?  I'm pretty sure you could tune that view however you would want.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you just supply the hint directly on the view:

```
select /*+ full(v) */ *
  from v
 where col3 < 999;
```

In case that doesn't work, you can also use include a `qb_name` hint in your view definition, and then reference that in the outer query:

```
create or replace view v as
   select /*+ qb_name(myblock)*/ *
     from t
    where col1 > 1000
      and col2 <> 'David';

select /*+ full(t@myblock) */ *
  from v
 where col3 < 999;
```

Comment: Your first solution will mperform full on all the tables in the view... in this example there is only 1 table. what if there are more?
I'm looking for a solution with no touching the view. onlt the outer query.

Comment: You can add the QB_NAME hint to the view definition without any impact to any existing code.